# Android TextView drawable, change padding between drawable and text?

Tags: android, textview, drawable, padding

I am creating a `TextView` with a drawable underneath, in a `GridLayout`.

I want to bring the drawable to the middle of the `TextView`; I tried with 
`setCompoundDrawablePadding(-75)` and it only changes the position of the text.

Current code:

```
    TextView secondItem = new TextView(this);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams second = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row2, col1);
    second.width = halfOfScreenWidth;
    second.height = (int) (quarterScreenWidth * 1.5);
    secondItem.setLayoutParams(second);
    secondItem.setBackgroundResource(R.color.MenuSecond);
    secondItem.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.ic_action_new);
    secondItem.setText("Text");
    secondItem.setCompoundDrawablePadding(-180);
    secondItem.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    secondItem.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large_Inverse);
    gridLayout.addView(secondItem, second);
```

How can I set the text and drawable to the middle of the `TextView`?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You'll need to combine `drawablePadding` and `padding` to get the desired result.

Comment: how would you combine it for different text (different locales for example)?

Answer (score 26):

**In XML:**

```
android:drawablePadding = paddingValue
```

or

**Programmatically:**

```
TextView txt;

txt.setCompoundDrawablePadding(paddingValue)
```

**android:drawablePadding** is the easiest way to give padding to the drawable icon but you can not give specific one side padding like **paddingRight** or **paddingLeft** of the drawable icon. This gives padding to either side of the drawable.

Answer (score 3):

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/otherapps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:text="@string/other_apps"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_more"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp" //for drawable padding to the left
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use layer-list.

Before:

[image]

Create xml for shape - shape_rectangle.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:right="5dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/my_color" />
        <size
            android:width="5dp"
            android:height="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

After:

[image]

In xml, there is something like `android:right`. You can add also `top`,`left`,`bottom`. This way you can give for example: padding left and right to drawable without resizing total height of textView.