# How to add margin and not padding to compoundDrawable

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, compound-drawables

I saw how to [add padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362762/android-textview-drawable-change-padding-between-drawable-and-text/19362934) to compoundDrawable.

But is there anyway to add margins?

```
    TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(displayName, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: What would that mean in the context of compound drawables, where it would be different than padding?

Answer (score 0):

**Setting margin is not possible for `TextView`**

As per my knowledge there is no official API to set margin for [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView).

You can only set `padding`.

Comment: can you please explain the relation between `TextViewCompat` and `compundDrawable`? the later is always in `TextViewCompat` ?

Comment: @EladBenda `compoundDrawable` is part of `TextView` and of course for backward compatibility it is available in `TextViewCompat` as well. I gave example `TextViewCompat` because in your question you referred to the same. I will update my answer to avoid any confusion. Thanks

Comment: @EladBenda is my answer not helping your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.
You can only create your ViewGroup and add TextView and ImageView to it. It is the simplest solution.

Comment: how did you verify it? I want to understand for the future

Comment: Just look at the `OnDraw()` method of the TextView. 
And how it draws mDrawables on it, it uses paddings to draw.
Also drawable is not a view and it can not have a margin.
Just create your custom view and place ImageView wherever you want